# The finite product of $L^p$ spaces is reflexive ($1<p<\infty$)

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

I am trying to understand the proof that the Sobolev Space $W^{1,p}$ is reflexive given in *Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations, by Haim Brezis*.

There it is used that the space $L^p(I) \times L^p(I)$ is reflexive, where I is an open interval (possibly not bounded). I understand this comes from the fact that $L^p(I)$  is indeed reflexive for $1<p<\infty$.

I need help showing that result. I haven't really worked with products of $L^p$ spaces and can't seem to find any basic information on it on the Internet.

Note: The same thing is done for proving the separability of $W^{1,p}$ for $1 \leq p < \infty$.

Comment: Btw to get what you want for $L^p$ you don't need anything. Note that for example $L^p([0,1])\approx L^p([1,2])$; hence $L^p([0,1])\times L^p([0,1])\approx L^p(]0,1])\times L^p(]1,2])\approx L^p([0,2])$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are reflexive Banach spaces then $X\times Y$ is reflexive. This follows from the fact that $(X\times Y)^*=X^*\times Y^*$.

Which is very easy. First, if $L_1$ and $L_2$ are bounded linear functionals on $X$ and $Y$ respectively and we define $$L(x,y)=L_1x+L_2y$$then it's clear that $L$ is a bounded linear functional on $X\times Y$. Conversely, if $L$ is a bounded linear functional on $X\times Y$, define $L_1:X\to\Bbb C$ and $L_2:Y\to\Bbb C$ by $$L_1x=L(x,0)$$and$$L_2y=L(0,y),$$ and it's clear that $L_1$ and $L_2$ are bounded, and that $$L(x,y)=L(x,0)+L(0,y)=L_1x+L_2y.$$

**Edit:** So $(X\times Y)^*=X^*\times Y^*$, in the sense that an element $(x^*,y^*)\in X^*\times Y^*$ defines a functional on $X\times Y$ via the pairing $\newcommand\ip[2]{\langle #1,#2\rangle}$ $$\ip{(x^*,y^*)}{(x,y)}=\ip{x^*}x+\ip{y^*}y.$$

So if $X$ and $Y$ are reflexive then $(X\times Y)^{**}=X^{**}\times Y^{**}=X\times Y$, so $X\times Y$ is reflexive.

It's been objected that that's not complete, since saying $X^{**}$ is isomorphic to $X$ does not imply $X$ is reflexive; for that we need that the *canonical* injection from $X$ into $X^{**}$ is surjective. It seems clear to me that since all of the mappings constructed above are "natural", the final one we constructed from $X$ to $X^{**}$ must also be "natural", so this really can't be a problem.

Luckily we don't have to try to prove that, since it's easy to verify directly that $X\times Y$ is reflexive. Indeed, suppose $L=(x^{**},y^{**})\in X^{**}\times Y^{**}$: $$L(x^*,y^*)=\ip{x^{**}}{x^*}+\ip{y^{**}}{y^*}.$$

Since $X$ and $Y$ are reflexive there exist $\alpha\in X$ and $\beta\in Y$ with $$\ip{x^{**}}{x^*}=\ip{x^*}\alpha,
\ip{y^{**}}{y^*}=\ip{y^*}\beta.$$Hence $$L(x^*,y^*)=\ip{x^*}\alpha+\ip{y^*}\beta=\ip{(x^*,y^*)}{(\alpha,\beta)}.$$

Which says "$L=(\alpha,\beta)$" (with the equals sign in the same spirit as in "$X^{**}=X$").

Comment: Okay, so your proof will give us the biyective isometry: $
\begin{matrix}
I:   \hspace{0.6cm} X^*\times Y^* \longrightarrow (X\times Y)^*\\ 
 (L_1,L_2)  \longrightarrow  L 
\end{matrix}$ Right?

Comment: Then we have $( L^{p} \times L^{p})^{**} = L^{p ** } \times L^{p **}=L^p \times L^p $ for $1 < p < \infty$.

Comment: @D1X Right.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Very simple argument! Nice! +1

Comment: Sorry but why having a bijective isometry from $X \times Y$ to the double dual implies reflectivity? The map must be James embedding, not any isometry. There exist spaces that are isometrically isomorphic to their double dual but not reflexive.

Comment: @EroSennin I didn't say anything (explicitly) about a bijective isometry to the double dual.

Comment: Look at the comment above of the OP. I cannot see why from this bijective isometry we conclude the reflexivity of the cartesian product.

Comment: We need some Eberlein-Smulian type of argument, like as bounded sequences admit convergent subsequences in the weak topology. Otherwise, I do not see the argument.

Comment: Perhaps. It still seems to me that it must be just as trivial as above: all the isomorphisms implicit in the equals signs are "natural", so the final bijection must be the natural one. Haven't quite written that down...

Comment: @EroSennin Fixed - as I suspected, nothing but definitions.

Comment: Perfect, now I definitely see why the isomorphisms were all natural. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @David C. Ullrich Hi,to conclude the isometric isomorphism,we use $\ell_1$ norm on each summand correct?That is $\|(x,y)\|_1 = \|x\|_X +\|y\|_Y$ correct?

Comment: @yili In fact if $||\cdot||_*$ is any norm on $\Bbb R^2$ we can say $||(x,y)||_{X\times Y}=||(||x||_X,||y||_Y)_*||$, because any two norms on $\Bbb R^2$ are equivalent.

Comment: @David C. Ullrich ,thanks I have notice this , isometric is stronger than equivalent norm, but this does not influce the properties of the space on both side,since metric are equivalent.